# How to configure Webpack to use ES2015 on the server?

Tags: node.js, webpack, ecmascript-6

I am using Webpack for an applicaiton that uses Javascript for both client and server-side development. I have loaded certain babel packages to enable me to use ES2015 version of Javascript on the client side. How do I configure my applicaiton to allow me to use ES2015 on the server side?

Comment: You just use babel without webpack. Or given a recent Node version, you don't transpile any ES6 at all but execute it natively.

Comment: Are you able to provide some confugration guidance on this, i.e. how to configure Node(?) to use ES6?

Comment: No extra configuration required, just invoke it.

Comment: Invoke it how??

Answer (score 1):

I ensured that a `.bablerc` file was in the root of my application (same location as `package.json`) and added the following to this file:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

I then installed the `babel-core` npm package and included the following line in my `server.js` (whichever file loads the server-side first) file:

```
require("babel-core/register");
```

After doing this I was able to use ES2015 features on the server-side.